# how to define a constant data table

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, datatable, constants

I am developing windows application in `C# .NET4` and using `SQL server 2008`, what I am trying to do is I want to store a table of a complicated formula values from `excell table` as constant and use the table values in my application the table is 2 dimension table and I do not have the formula and I think this way is faster than storing common values in the application and use them, rather than calculating it each and every time. First i stored data in the data base and  used it, but there is a problem here that I can not insert these values in the data base each time the program is installing in the computer this data should not be manipulated so I want to store my table in a constant data table I `googled` it but nothing came up, so what is the most efficient way for storing tables as constants.the table contains at least 5000 rows so it is not good to define 5000 constants.

Comment: You don't need a constant, you need a variable that you will read the table data into, possibly from a constant excel file path.

Comment: What I want is not to move the excell file in every computer that i install

Comment: 1. Why not? 2. If you insist, let the server serve it.

Comment: So you mean that i use this datatable as application resource ?whether it is data set or excell?

Comment: Yes. It's like you have an xml configuration resource. This one is just huge and I don't know why you need it, but that's your call.